# How to implement download data option for web app

Tags: django, database, postgresql, dictionary, download

I am developing a feature to a web app ( dictionary-like app ) - a download option. It means that a user can request to download data ( of certain models ).
As a reference I can mention the download button here https://wals.info/languoid.
I want to keep the files that I want to download up to date and it consists of millions of records.

*Example...* I want to download all the words of English language in some format (word, csv etc). Querying everything from the db would be impossible as it would take a lot of time.

I am using Django framework with a postgreDB.

Can you suggest me some efficient way of approaching that.

Comment: Since you have the data in the database, you would normally schedule a job to convert to specified format and then send an email with a download link when done. Is this acceptable? The other option would be to stream the query results and transform on the fly to browser response, but that's an easy way to DOS your server and any interruption in connection would not be resumable.

Comment: Except the DOS that you are mentioning, it would also take a lot of time to prepare all the data from the database. I as thinking of keeping some files as a backup and when we update the DB we also update the files as well. I am not 100% sure if that would be efficient or there is some better way...

Comment: If you have mostly static database with scheduled periodic updates (as opposed to a constantly changing one), then it makes sense to schedule update tasks for the files as well. This you can do with a pipelines / workflows using task queues like Celery, [Rundeck](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#workflow-definition) or [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/cookbook.html#pipelines).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to check import-export module:

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I think that it has all you need.

Comment: Why? It solves nothing, cause he would need to store all english words in postgres first then export it, which takes even longer.

Comment: @Melvyn but he IS mentioning postgres, so the data is already there, isn't it? Or I got it wrong.

Comment: "Querying everything from the db would be impossible as it would take a lot of time." - and then transforming it - it's going to time out. He would really need a queue and predictable but possibly unique urls.

Comment: data is already there, the thing is that it would take a lot of time to query millions of rows and I was thinking that keeping some backup files and updating them would be a good way. I am not sure if there is some better way.

Comment: Online querying - absolutely, but preparing files with scheduled database queries looks doable to me.

Comment: Maybe you can export just new words from dictionary and add that to previous files?

Comment: "Maybe you can export just new words from dictionary and add that to previous files?" - that's what I am thinking, it seems safer and the db wouldn't need to be queried each time a user wants to download something.

Comment: It depends how often you add words to the dictionary, and if the, lets say daily or hourly snapshot would work for you users.